# Allow User to Copy Images in Java Swing Application?

Tags: java, image, swing

I have a java swing project I have been working on that involves parsing text data and then displaying graphical representations through local image files. I want the user to be able to copy the images displayed so that they can be pasted into other programs (such as Microsoft Word). It doesn't even need to happen like that, just any way I can make .jpg files copied so the user can paste them elsewhere. There would be a long chain of images, so just copying and pasting one at a time is not a possibility. Please help!

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) - I know you're not trying to do DnD, but this is where Data Transfer begins...

Comment: That long chain needs to be represented as one image depending how it was coded.   If there are many images to save, then just loop and save them.

Answer (score 2):

So, I threw this together really quickly and it works just fine for me.

Basically, you should be able to "export" just about any `java.awt.Image` based image, including `BufferedImage`

**Updated, now with improved stiching...**

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageTransfer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage left = ImageIO.read(new File("left"));
            BufferedImage right = ImageIO.read(new File("right"));

            BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
                    left.getWidth() + right.getWidth(),
                    Math.max(left.getHeight(), right.getHeight()),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
            g2d.drawImage(left, 0, (img.getHeight() - left.getHeight()) / 2, null);
            g2d.drawImage(right, left.getWidth(), (img.getHeight() - right.getHeight()) / 2, null);
            g2d.dispose();

            final Clipboard cb = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            cb.setContents(new ImageTransferable(img), new ClipboardOwner() {
                @Override
                public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
                    System.out.println("You Lose");
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class ImageTransferable implements Transferable {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public ImageTransferable(BufferedImage img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{DataFlavor.imageFlavor};
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return DataFlavor.imageFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }
            return img;
        }

    }

}
```

Note, while I loaded the image from a file, the image could be created dynamically in memory as well and it should work just fine...

Take a look at [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html), [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) for more details

Comment: This is a great example. So say I wanted to put more than one image onto the clipboard at a time so I can paste multiple images with one command. Is that a possibility?

Comment: You can't put multiple images into the clipboard, but you could stitch them together into a single image and paste that to the clipboard

Comment: I see. If you don't mind, could you edit your example to incorporate putting two pictures side by side into one and pasting it? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you. You are a beautiful person. This is so helpful; you just made my day!